# H subgroup of G such that H=Inn(G)=Z(G)

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that the condition in the title is fulfilled. What can be said about $H$? Is it finite? Cyclic?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $H$ is certainly abelian since it is a center and elements of the center commute with the entire group.

Comment: Elements of the center induce the trivial  automorphisms since they commute with all elements of the group.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean $H=Z(G) \cong {\rm Inn }(G)$?

Comment: @Derek Holt: yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ${\rm Inn}(G) \cong G/Z(G)$, you are asking about groups with $Z(G) \cong G/Z(G)$. Such groups are nilpotent of class $2$.

It is easy to show that $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic, so $Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic. In fact $G/Z(G)$ cannot be a $2$-generator group, or else $Z(G)$ would be cyclic, so $G/Z(G)$ and $Z(G)$ have at least $3$ generators.

There are examples of order $p^6$ for all primes $p$ and the smallest example has order $64$. There are also infinite examples, so you cannot say that $H$ is finite.